# Gerund or Infinitive? (an example sentence)

Tags: meaning, infinitive-vs-gerund

Which sentence is right?

> 1. I think there is a hidden agenda in the proposal **to reduce** the staff in order to make the company more efficient.

> 2. I think there is a hidden agenda in the proposal **reducing** the staff in order to make the company more efficient.

---

If both are correct, are there any differences in their meaning?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: No. I have recently started learning English, in self-study and it's a personal question.

Comment: You propose **to do** something.

Comment: Honestly, we have no way of knowing which of these are true (factual). You wrote a sentence saying that you think there is a hidden agenda; however, you may be lying.

Comment: A proposal can't reduce anything (until it becomes adopted policy) so "... the proposal reducing the staff ..." doesn't make much sense.  It is a proposal (formal suggestion) to reduce staff.  If adopted as policy, it becomes a policy of reducing staff. As in "the company has a policy of reducing staff."